# Turning off the shading/hatching feature in section view

Tags: autodesk-forge

In Forge viewer, in the section mode, if a clipping plane cut through an object, the cutting surface would be shaded in yellow with black hatches. I am wondering if there is any way to turn off the shading/hatching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no official way to disable the cap meshes.

If you're interested in hacky solutions: the Section tool inserts the cap meshes into two specially named objects in the scene that you can remove (although keep in mind that the extension will recreate these objects as soon as you move the section plane again):

```js
const section3D = viewer.scene.getObjectByName('section3D');
if (section3D)
    viewer.scene.remove(section3D);
const section2D = viewer.sceneAfter.getObjectByName('section2D');
if (section2D)
    viewer.sceneAfter.remove(section2D);
```

Comment: Petr, thanks for the answer. This is a forge function to which we don't have access. I am wondering where I should put the code you provided? Should I inserted it in the code related to launching forge viewer? Thanks.

Comment: There are different moments you could run this code snippet. For example, whenever the section planes change, using the `Autodesk.Viewing.CUTPLANES_CHANGE_EVENT` event. All you need to run the code is just a reference to the `viewer`.